# C ternary operator

Tags: c, ternary-operator

While studying C I faced something that is completely confusing my mind.

The expression is:

```
exp(V*log(i))?i%2?s:s--:s++;
```

If ternary operator is Question?Positive:Negative; I thought it was something like:

```
if(pow(i,V)==1&&(i%2)==0)
    s--;
 else
    s++;
```

However, the **s** does not enter in the question, should I ask what does the first expression mean?

The program worked perfectly, but I could not understand why.

The original program is:

```
main(){
    #define V 1

    int a, s=0, i;
    for(i=1000;i>=0;i--)
        exp(V*log(i))?i%2?s:s--:s++;
    exp(V*log(i))?printf("%d\t%d\t",-s,i):printf("%d\t%d\t", s,-i);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: A couple of extra parentheses would make this much clearer.

Comment: Read about [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If exp(V*log(i)) is true then test is it odd i%2==1  if it is return s if even return s-- if exp(V*log(i)) is false return s++
If you write it like this than is easier to see:

```
exp(V*log(i))?(i%2?s:s--):s++;
```

Comment: Humm.. Thank you very much. It makes completely sense.

Comment: You are welcome. Naturally I swapped odd and even in explanation. Will repair it now.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator tests if an expression is true. To understand this case you need to analyse it and separate the two uses of the operator:

```
exp(V*log(i))?i%2?s:s--:s++;
```

This translates to

```
if(exp(V*log(i))
    if(i%2)
       s;
    else
       s--;
else
    s++;
```

The only difference is that it is an expression and a single statement instead of the `if`/`else` version. It always returns the current value of `s` but changes it depending on the condition.

If `exp` refers to the exponential function, then unless the output is `-inf` the output will be `!=0` so the value will evaluate to `true`. Note that `nan` will also evaluate to false and `nan` is the output for `log` when the value is outside its domain.

So basically you could translate this with a much simpler expression (unless V is zero, the value for `i==0` would change):

```
i>0?s++:i%2?s:s--;
```